# Drawing a window in python

Tags: python

I am drawing a window in python that should look like this:

```
+----+----+
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
+----+----+
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
+----+----+
```

I have tried the following code:

```
 y = 4
 i = x
 def window(x):
     for x in range(x, 0, -1):
        if x == i:
            print("+----+----+")
        elif x == 1:
            print("+----+----+")
        else:
            print("|", "  ", "|", "  ", "|")
            print("|", "  ", "|", "  ", "|")
 window(y)
```

I get only half of the result.

Comment: "I am drawing a window in python that must look like this:" ...??  I think we are missing this part.

Comment: Yes, I am working on it.

Answer (score 1):

For your consideration, you might utilize the modulo operation in the following context.

```
y = 4

def window(x):
    for z in range(0, 2 *(x + 1) + 1):
        if z % (x + 1) == 0:
            print("+----+----+")
        else:
            print("|", "  ", "|", "  ", "|")

window(y)
```

Here is a sample output from the terminal when run.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Window$ python3 Pane.py 
+----+----+
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
+----+----+
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
|    |    |
+----+----+
```

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works on me as well.

Comment: @JosephBadanaRivera Please remember to accept answers when they provide the solution to your question.